# How to handle AppBar buttons when in Snapped view

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a bottom app bar containing 4 buttons at the moment, and the time has come where a few more need to be added.

Now all is fine if you're viewing in full screen mode, or filled, but when you snap the app to the side and then open up the app bar, all the buttons overlap each other. The problem is that I do not know how I should handle this, and I cannot find anything online that addresses this issue.

The buttons on the right pertain to the document/file itself, such as New, Open, Save, etc. And the ones on the right are more for editing purposes. What I want to happen is that when the app is snapped to the side, the editing app bar buttons should not be displayed, only the New, Open and Save ones should.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should design your app bar separately for snapped view, here is the article that describes options that you have:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj662742.aspx

Basically you can resize buttons in snapped mode, show buttons in two or more rows, or do separate design for snapped view.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to show some appbar buttons OR none. Use visual state manager to control visibility